# Parsing URI in .NET

Tags: c#, uri

### Short Version

Is there a class in .NET that can parse Uri's?

### Background

The Windows Search service registers content to crawl through the use of URIs. Using [**ISearchCrawlScopeManager**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266485.aspx) you can enumerate the various root uri's:

- `csc://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/`
- `defaultroot://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/`
- `file:///C:\`
- `file:///D:\`
- `iehistory://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/`
- `mapi://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/Outlook2003/Inbox/`
- `winrt://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/`

Unfortunately the .NET [**Uri** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) is unable to parse these Uri's ([dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywYcHR)):

```
Run-time exception (line 8): Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Stack Trace:

[System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.]
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
```

Is there a class in .NET that can parse Uri's?

The native Win32 function **[InternetCrackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** is able to correctly handle the Uri:

```
URL_COMPONENTS components;
components.dwStructSize      = sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS );
components.dwSchemeLength    = DWORD(-1);
components.dwHostNameLength  = DWORD(-1);
components.dwUserNameLength  = DWORD(-1);
components.dwPasswordLength  = DWORD(-1);
components.dwUrlPathLength   = DWORD(-1);
components.dwExtraInfoLength = DWORD(-1);

InternetCrackUrl(url, Length(url), 0, ref components);

mapi://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/Outlook2003/Inbox/
\__/   \__________________________________________/\_________________/
 |                           |                              _
Scheme                    HostName                       UrlPath

Scheme:   "mapi"
HostName: "{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}"
UrlPath:  "/Outlook2003/Inbox/"
```

### Bonus Chatter

Apply Uri escaping to a uri:

- **Before**: `mapi://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/Outlook2003/Inbox/`
- **After**: `mapi://%7BS-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010%7D/Outlook2003/Inbox/`

doesn't help ([dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pIKNjW)).

**Difference between Uri and Url?**

Urls are a subset of Uris

- Uri tells you a thing
- Url tells you where to get a thing

E.g.:

- **URI**: `isbn:1631971727` *(identifies a thing)*

  - **URL**: `isbn://amazon.com/1631971727` *(where to get a thing)*

## Url

The breakdown of a URL is:

```
  foo://iboyd:Trubador@example.com:8042/look/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \___/ \______/ \_________/ \__/\______________/\__________/ \__/
   |      |      |         |        |         |            |         |
scheme username password  host     port     path         query    fragment
```

- **Scheme**: `foo`
- **Username**: `iboyd`
- **Password**: [Trubador](https://xkcd.com/936/)
- **Host**: `example.com`
- **Port**: `8042`
- **Path**: `/look/over/there`
- **Query**: `?name=ferret`
- **Fragment**: `nose`

Comment: `System.Uri` can parse `file:///C:/` and `file:///D:/` with no issues. The other schemes are not supported by the class. Is there anything in the Windows Search SDK for parsing these? The kind of library you're searching for (or may need to write) likely depends on what you want to do after parsing them.

Answer (score 1):

The method `ResolveHelper()`that called by `CreateThis()` as you see in the stack trace is indentifing it as an absolute uri hence it throws an exception.

change your uri from:

```
mapi://{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/Outlook2003/Inbox/
```

to:

```
mapi:////{S-1-5-21-397955417-62688126-188441444-1010}/Outlook2003/Inbox/
```

[.Net source code - ResolveHelper() method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs,d71b39e7926f88c6,references)

**

> FROM Reference Source .NET Framework 4.7.2:

**

```
internal static Uri ResolveHelper(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri, ref string newUriString, ref bool userEscaped, 
            out UriFormatException e)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!baseUri.IsNotAbsoluteUri && !baseUri.UserDrivenParsing, "Uri::ResolveHelper()|baseUri is not Absolute or is controlled by User Parser.");

            e = null;
            string relativeStr = string.Empty;

            if ((object)relativeUri != null)
            {
                if (relativeUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    return relativeUri;

                relativeStr = relativeUri.OriginalString;
                userEscaped = relativeUri.UserEscaped;
            }
            else
                relativeStr = string.Empty;

            // Here we can assert that passed "relativeUri" is indeed a relative one

            if (relativeStr.Length > 0 && (IsLWS(relativeStr[0]) || IsLWS(relativeStr[relativeStr.Length - 1])))
                relativeStr = relativeStr.Trim(_WSchars);

            if (relativeStr.Length == 0)
            {
                newUriString = baseUri.GetParts(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, 
                    baseUri.UserEscaped ? UriFormat.UriEscaped : UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
                return null;
            }

            // Check for a simple fragment in relative part
            if (relativeStr[0] == '#' && !baseUri.IsImplicitFile && baseUri.Syntax.InFact(UriSyntaxFlags.MayHaveFragment))
            {
                newUriString = baseUri.GetParts(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Fragment, 
                    UriFormat.UriEscaped) + relativeStr;
                return null;
            }

            // Check for a simple query in relative part
            if (relativeStr[0] == '?' && !baseUri.IsImplicitFile && baseUri.Syntax.InFact(UriSyntaxFlags.MayHaveQuery))
            {
                newUriString = baseUri.GetParts(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Query & ~UriComponents.Fragment, 
                    UriFormat.UriEscaped) + relativeStr;
                return null;
            }

            // Check on the DOS path in the relative Uri (a special case)
            if (relativeStr.Length >= 3
                && (relativeStr[1] == ':' || relativeStr[1] == '|')
                && IsAsciiLetter(relativeStr[0])
                && (relativeStr[2] == '\\' || relativeStr[2] == '/'))
            {

                if (baseUri.IsImplicitFile)
                {
                    // It could have file:/// prepended to the result but we want to keep it as *Implicit* File Uri
                    newUriString = relativeStr;
                    return null;
                }
                else if (baseUri.Syntax.InFact(UriSyntaxFlags.AllowDOSPath))
                {
                    // The scheme is not changed just the path gets replaced
                    string prefix;
                    if (baseUri.InFact(Flags.AuthorityFound))
                        prefix = baseUri.Syntax.InFact(UriSyntaxFlags.PathIsRooted) ? ":///" : "://";
                    else
                        prefix = baseUri.Syntax.InFact(UriSyntaxFlags.PathIsRooted) ? ":/" : ":";

                    newUriString = baseUri.Scheme + prefix + relativeStr;
                    return null;
                }
                // If we are here then input like "http://host/path/" + "C:\x" will produce the result  http://host/path/c:/x
            }


            ParsingError err = GetCombinedString(baseUri, relativeStr, userEscaped, ref newUriString);

            if (err != ParsingError.None)
            {
                e = GetException(err);
                return null;
            }

            if ((object)newUriString == (object)baseUri.m_String)
                return baseUri;

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I certainly can't have prior knowledge of every Uri that the .NET parser cannot handle in order to trick the .NET parser into not crashing. Also, changing it to `////` causes it to not fail: but it also returns incorrect results (the host is missing, the query is missing)